# Making a carpet texture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, texture

Hello all the awesome designers out there,

I would like to create a texture design like this carpet in the photo (see arrow)
[image]

Any suggestions on how I could achieve creating that texture+color in the photoshop?

Maybe doing it section by section?
So far I have something like this...

[image]

It doesn't look quite right.

Any idea would help. Thank you very much!

Comment: I, would cheat. [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&tbs=simg:CAESWhpYCxCwjKcIGjwKOggCEhSvDo0IihWJFc8h0AqsFKoOrQ6uDhogG_1isEIXoYai5S65UAvweKCBaVc_1jblBo75KL4-rfisAMCxCOrv4IGgoKCAgBEgQDlPJoDA&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=hFIPVKaREaO1igLMqoHQBg&ved=0CDEQsw4&biw=1202&bih=1356&q=rug%20braided) for a square image and make the texture pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I interpreted the question correctly but: If you need to make a repeating texture out of a normal texture just cut and rearrange it like this:

[image]

After that you only need to fix the image so it looks normal again and the outer edges automagically line up with it's repeated neighbour.

Comment: You can quickly rearrange the quadrants with an [Offset Filter](http://www.designbash.com/photoshop/photoshop-offset-filter-making-seamless-textures/)